# Create Login System with JAXB and EclipseLink

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to create an XML schema that contains

```
<root>
<login>
    <username> </username>
    <paswword> </paswword>
</login>
</root>
```

How can i read this values and use them for authentication, with or without JAXB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the XML schema of your document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="paswword" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="username" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="login"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="login">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="username"/>
                <xs:element ref="paswword"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Give that schema to some king of script that you are using to generate JAXB objects, pack them into a jar, put it into your classpath and use for your any purposes.